# Does [39:42] in Qur'an contradict lucid dreaming?

Tags: quran

Does the following verse has anything to do with lucid dreams?

> “It is Allah Who takes away the souls at the time of their death, and those that die not during their sleep. He keeps those (souls) for which He has ordained death and sends the rest for a term appointed. Verily, in this are signs for a people who think deeply.”
>
> [az-Zumar 39:42](https://legacy.quran.com/39/42)

I'm so confused as to what the above verses mean. Does it mean that we don't have a will to induce lucid dreams? Are lucid dreams even real or not? Because Allah only Has the power to give us our souls back so we can wake up from sleep.

I want some answers please!

Comment: [6:60](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://legacy.quran.com/6/60&ved=2ahUKEwjHzZTJuc76AhWB-aQKHUFEBXYQFnoECBEQAQ&usg=AOvVaw0c1ru7lX80R9Qnf8XDrAEi) is also similar.

Answer (score 1):

---

According to [Islamqa](https://islamqa.info/en/answers/182280/comment-on-so-called-lucid-dreaming-or-controlling-ones-dreams) lucid dreaming is quote *"figment of the imagination "* and a *"myth"* .

> Controlling one’s dreams means that the sleeper is in a state of awareness whilst he is dreaming. That is because sleep is akin to death, and sleep is called mawt (death) in the Qur’an and Sunnah. Allah, may He be glorified and exalted, says (interpretation of the meaning}:
>
> “It is Allah Who takes away the souls at the time of their death, and those that die not during their sleep. He keeps those (souls) for which He has ordained death and sends the rest for a term appointed. Verily, in this are signs for a people who think deeply”
> [az-Zumar 39:42].
>
> All these events that those who believe in it see and talk about are natural things that happen to people. Sometimes a person’s dream may be so clear and logical that it is as if he is awake. And sometimes the dreams come from the shayaateen (devils) toying with the sleeper. Sometimes a person is in a state between sleep and wakefulness, but this is not an intermediate state; rather sometimes he is asleep and sometimes he is awake, and it cannot be anything but these two alternatives.
>
> All the types of dreams that these studies speak about are things that indeed happen to all people. **But analyzing them and claiming to have control of them is a figment of the imagination.**
>
> **It is very unfortunate that this is a myth that is dressed up as science, like Darwinism. It may be opening the door to the shayaateen to toy with you, and you may think that it is a kind of self-control and discovering hidden worlds, when it is nothing more than shayaateen.**

---

On Assim Al Hakeem YouTube channel, [this](https://youtu.be/tcMt5YvrhVQ) was his view on lucid dreaming:

> Lucid dreaming when I googled it, I found out that people claim it's a type of a dream that you have
> control over and this is like saying being tall and short at the same time this is not possible, How can you have control over your dreams? We know that
> once you are asleep you are unconscious. You are gone from this world you don't know what's happening and you have no control over your dreams, yeah in science and fiction movies.

(This text was taken from YouTube transcript and is slightly edited for clarity)

---

I couldn't find other fatwa sites views/stance on lucid dreaming rather the question whether is it halal or haram by [Islamqa.org/hanafi](https://islamqa.org/hanafi/themufti/152563/is-lucid-dreaming-permissible/) and [islamweb.net](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.islamweb.net/amp/en/fatwa/308950/). So one could assume they don't think lucid dreaming is a "myth"  or "figment of the imagination" .

Comment: Thanks AbduRahman, I searched a lot on the web and couldn't find lots of information about whether lucid dreaming is halal or Haram... I'm doing my best and still didn't figure out if it is halal or Haram.    Any help???

Comment: Having experienced it myself multiple times, I don't agree that it is myth. It is just a dream in which you have the awareness that it is a dream, you can visually see stuff while knowing that it is not real. You also have control, although it is limited.

Comment: @UmH Or perhaps the sensation of control is part of the dream itself. I've experienced it as well, but can't say.

Comment: @UmH I also had few dreams where I knew I was dreaming however the only thing I thought of, was trying to open my eyes which ended waking me up.

Comment: @Omaro79 I provided two links at the end of my answer please refer to them.